# How to reinstall display manager, window manager, and desktop environment?

Tags: display, pantheon, window-manager, gnome, desktop-environment

I was on elementaryOS Loki and I clicked the Update button on AppCenter which brought my elementaryOS to 5.1 Hera. After various days I noticed that any applications that are not cured for elementaryOS, for example Firefox, Visual Studio Code, Unity (game engine), etc, don't work properly when you open a gui to save a file. The top navigation for saving files doesn't work on non cured applications. In the case of Unity, the clicks anywhere on the user interface don't match the position of the cursor. The same sometimes happens in Firefox.

I wanted to know if there is a way to reinstall the display manager, the desktop environment, and the window manager.

I have access to safe mode so I don't mind booting into it to completely uninstall those, reboot, and then do a clean install of them again if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to give `sudo apt install --reinstall elementary-desktop` a try and report if that fixed it for you.

-Aldo

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I marked it as a solution because that answers the question that was asked even though it didn't fix my problem because it looks like the problem is not a fault from the desktop. I think it is a GTK issue. I noticed that the same happens with Code which is an elementary application. I've been also noticing that since Freya, every time there is an upgrade, something with GTK gets messed up and because it's so hard to pinpoint, the only solution has always been a clean install of the OS instead of trying to fix GTK.

Comment: I created a live disk of elementary and installed it on the same partition on the same mount point to not delete my data and now things are working properly. Because I installed it on the same partition and didn't format, the installer only deleted certain conflicting system files. It didn't remove any user configurations in the home folder. That makes me think that when the upgrade happened from Loki to Hera, it upgraded GTK and didn't remove the previous version or configure it properly on the system files. Now the File Explorer and file saving dialogs look different than before and work.